# I'm experiencing confusion regarding Service and UseCase

Tags: node.js, architecture

I am currently working as a NodeJS developer. While practicing and applying what I have learned, I have been encountering confusion between Service and UseCase, so I am reaching out for help.

The project I am currently working on is structured with a 3-Layer architecture (Controller - Service - Repository). The Services are currently implemented using the singleton pattern.

However, some of the methods in the Services are performing too many tasks. For example, the accounting-related Service has around 30 methods, and some of them have 200-300 lines of code.

Therefore, I am considering extracting common logic into UseCases. But I have a question: When extracting this logic into UseCases, should I implement them using the singleton pattern? Or is it fine to write them as regular classes?

Currently, I have written them as regular classes, and to execute the business logic, I use the 'new' keyword. I initially chose this approach because I wanted to perform parameter validation in the constructor function. However, I am concerned about potential memory wastage due to using the 'new' operator for each request.

I would like to know how to properly structure UseCases for optimal design.